# linear transformation between Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, linear-transformations

[image]

By definition, $|T|=\sup|(Tf,g)|, |f|\le1,|g|\le1$

$$||T||\ge(Tf,f)$$

But I can not find an example such that
$||T||>(Tf,f)$ for any $|f|<1$.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance~

Comment: Consider the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 0):

So, use the matrix suggested by Jose27 for the operator $T$, take a 2*1 vector (x,y) whose norm is bounded by 1, then ($T$(x,y),(x,y)) is ((0,x),(x,y))=xy has maximum 1/2.  While the norm of $T$ is 1.

I am not sure what is the intuition of this, why the equality defines the norm does not hold when g=f?